# Sending an empty array from ajax gave a null parameter in ASP.NET MVC action

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple ajax call like:

```
$.ajax({
   url: ... ,
   data: { anArray: [] },
   ...
});
```

and the controller's action:

```
public ActionResult Test(int[] anArray) {
   ...
}
```

seems that `anArray` is null instead of empty array.

I tried also with

- `List<int>`
- `string[]`
- `object[]`

but for all of above, I see null for `anArray` parameter.

I read similar questions but there are related to model parameters, I don't have, here, model.

How to receive an empty array in controller's action ? What should I do ?

Comment: have you add dataType to your ajax call?Your data does't reach to action method

Comment: i want to see if correct content type is set like, `contentType:"application/json"`.

Comment: Even I put that content type, same thing: null

Comment: Is it a post or get? I've found with C#'s MVC I typically need to put `dataType: 'json'` as well as @Jai's suggestion. Further, you should be able to simply do `data: []`.

Comment: This is by design. Just check for null.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that MVC maps empty arrays to a null; this is by design for some reason. I guess you can't do much with an array of zero items anyway.

It seems that your best bet is to instantiate the array yourself if it does come through as null:

```
        public ActionResult Test(int[] anArray)
        {
            anArray = anArray ?? new int[0];

            //...
        }
```